# SQL SELECT CASE with Where From Looping Value

Tags: mysql, while-loop, conditional-statements, case, where-clause

I have 2 tables :
table names transaction and detail customer

transaction table fields are idtrans and idcust.

detail customer fields are idcust and custname.

i have Problem with my php syntax, i want select table with condition from value lopping, here's my code:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql="select * from transaction";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sqlid="select * from detailcust where idcust='$row[idcust]')";
        $resultid= $conn->query($sqlid);
        if ($resultid->num_rows > 0){
        while ($rowid= mysqli_fetch_array($resultid)){
            $custname=$rowid["custname"];
    echo $custname;
    }
```

result name always first idcust value.

Answer (score 0):

You *seem to* want the names of customer that have at least one transaction. If so, no need for loops and multiple queries. You can get the result you want with just one query:

```
select c.*
from detailcust c
where exists (select 1 from transaction t where t.idcust = c.idcust)
```